# Payment method is not showing up in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, payment-gateway, citrus-engine

i am a newbie in open cart and is currently working on open cart. I installed the payment module in adminsitrator. When checking out from the front end, the payment method is not opening up and working.I thought that there might be a problem with the extension, so i uninstalled it still the payment method is not working. Any help?
I am using Citrus payment method(Indian gateway)

Comment: When debugging it with the firebug, it is showing me the following error:- 
$('.colorbox').colorbox({

Comment: Please explain it briefly...I can`t understand what do u want it..payment module will show in admin panel go to methods: Extension-> payments-> what your payment show, u just enable it and its will show in frontend

Comment: I installed a payment extension in admin panel, enabled it and on front end on checkout process. The payment method option is not displaying anything.Before all the process are working fine but when it goes to payment method it is not showing any payment method to choose. In my admin panel, i enabled citrus payment and cash on deliever method

Comment: what is version of your opencart ? and also version of your payment extension.Please verify your extension which is applicable for your opencart version.

Comment: I am using open cart version 1.5.5 and taken that citrus payment gateway extension from the official citrus company. When installing on my administrator panel. It is showing that error in loading the language file. so i changed the code of loading the language file after that it is working fine except in front end :(

Comment: thank you for communicate with me...

Comment: My problem has been solved now. Thanks for giving me your time. I really appreciate about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okays, i finally found the solution. The main problem that it is unable to call the colorbox function on my payment_method.tpl file. So what i have done is to comment the $('.colorbox')
whole javascript function. After that it worked completely fine. So guys, if you are having any kinds of problem in any checkout process mainly due to that javascript function then just comment it and it will work fine:-

catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('.colorbox').colorbox({
    width: 640,
    height: 480
});
//--></script>
```

just comment that script and it will work fine.Thanks and have a nice day ahead :)